# Homotopy theory of topological stacks/orbifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stacks, orbifolds

### Motivation $\newcommand{\T}{\mathscr{T}}$

I have many times found myself saying some variant of the following. Let $\T_g$ be the Teichmüller space of a surface of genus $g$, and $\Gamma_g$ its mapping class group. The quotient $\T_g/\Gamma_g$ is the moduli space of curves $M_g$. It is a deep fact that $\T_g$ is in fact diffeomorphic a ball, which implies that $M_g$ is a model for the classifying space $B\Gamma_g$ of the mapping class group. In particular, the cohomology of $M_g$ is just the group cohomology of $\Gamma_g$.

...well, almost. Since $\Gamma_g$ does not act freely, $M_g$ is in fact not a $B\Gamma_g$. However, all the stabilizers are finite groups, and this implies via a spectral sequence argument that the *rational* cohomology of $M_g$ coincides with the rational cohomology of $\Gamma_g$.

Most algebraic geometers seem to ignore these issues by working instead with stacks or orbifolds. Indeed, the *stack quotient* $[\T_g/\Gamma_g]$ is the *moduli stack* of curves $\mathcal M_g$, which is in any case the more fundamental object of study.

### Question

My question is whether the topological arguments in the first two paragraph can be carried out in a more highbrow way using orbifolds or topological stacks. I am vaguely aware that Noohi's work on topological stacks includes setting up a homotopy theory of topological stacks, but I know almost nothing about any of this. So the question should be interpreted as "does there exist a developed homotopy theory of topological stacks where the following question can be asked and answered".

> **Question 1**. Are any two quotients $[E/G]$ and $[E'/G]$, where $E$ and $E'$ are contractible spaces with a not necessarily free group action by $G$, homotopy equivalent as topological stacks?

My second question is more speculative since I know even less about rational homotopy theory.

> **Question 2**. Let $\mathcal X$ be a topological stack, with coarse moduli space $X$. Suppose that all isotropy groups of $\mathcal X$ are torsion. Is $\mathcal X \to X$ a rational homotopy equivalence?

Comment: This is only tangentially relevant, but Teichmueller space is not in fact a complex ball (as is usually defined). It is a complex manifold diffeomorphic to a real ball.

Comment: I don't think a positive answer to Q1 is reasonable since the analogue for spaces is false.

Comment: Jeff answer below corrects my intuition. I should have thought twice about Q1. Indeed, stacks are designed to make all actions (virtually) free!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a simple way to talk about the homotopy type of a stack.  Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be a stack and $f: U \to \mathfrak{X}$ a representable surjective submersion (an atlas) from a space $U$ (e.g., the map from the Teichmuller space to the moduli stack.)  Now, form the pullback of $f$ along itself:  $U\times_{\mathfrak{X}} U$.  This comes with two maps to $U$ and there is a diagonal map from $U \to U\times_{\mathfrak{X}} U$.  All together, these maps give a topological groupoid.  The nerve of this topological groupoid is a simplicial space and the geometric realization of which is a space that one can regard as representing the homotopy type of the stack.

Here are some easy/nice properties of the above notion of homotopy type that are easy to check.

1. Given a space $X$ with a $G$ action, the homotopy type of $[X/G]$ is the Borel construciton, aka homotopy quotient, $EG \times_G X$.  In particular, the answer to your Question 1 is affirmative, and the homotopy type of the moduli stack of curves is exactly $B\Gamma_g$.
2. One can define singular and de Rham cohomology of a stack and these invariants coincide with the integral and rational cohomology of the homotopy type of the stack.  This is in fact almost a tautology since, for example, the de Rham cohomology can be defined by taking a covering by a manifold, forming iterated pullbacks (to produce a simplicial manifold), taking the de Rham algebra of this simplicial manifold to get a cosimplicial dga, and then taking the totalization to get a dga.
3. It follows from property 1 above that the answer to your question 2 is also affirmative.
4. [Edit] This notion of homotopy type is well-defined because one can check that any two atlases determine Morita equivalent topological groupoids which then have weakly equivalent nerves.

If I remember correctly, Noohi uses a slightly more sophisticated notion of homotopy type.  He defines a universal weak equivalence to be a representable morphism from a space $U$ to a stack $\mathfrak{X}$ such that the pullback along any morphism from a space to $\mathfrak{X}$ is a weak equivalence.  $U$ can then be regarded as the homotopy type of the stack.  I think this is more of less equivalent to the naive version I explained above, but it has the advantage of being a bit more functorial and there might be some other technical advantages I can't remember.  David Carchedi will probably be able to give more details.

Comment: Thanks! This definition of homotopy type does make things clear.

Comment: can I ask a naive question? If I start with a (complex) algebraic stack X then I imagine I'd get an associated (analytic/topological) stack X(C) and run the same argument to obtain a homotopy type. Are there any pathologies when the stack X is singular (as an algebraic stack)?

Comment: Also, are there any good references for the cohomology of simplicial spaces?

Comment: @Jacob, I should have been a little more careful.  I was starting with a stack in the category of smooth manifolds (or topological spaces).  You're correct in that if we start with a complex algebraic stack then we should first pass to the associated analytic stack.  If it is nonsingular then forgetting the complex analytic structure gives a stack in manifolds.  If it is singular then you still get a stack in topological spaces, which still has a homotopy type as I described  The only part where you need manifolds is for de Rham forms.

Comment: I was going to say, but you clarified in your comment, that the original question never mentions manifolds, as far as I can tell, whereas you do use de Rham forms. But for stacks in the category of manifolds, I totally agree with what you say there.

Comment: I'm wondering, though, can you elaborate a bit on your point 3 that Q1 implies Q2? Without thinking much, I would be very happy to bet large amounts of money that the answer to Q2 is in fact affirmative, but without thinking much I also don't immediately see a complete argument.

Comment: If you build the Borel construction in the right way then the map from the homotopy quotient to the coarse quotient will have as its fibres the classifying spaces of the isotropy groups.  If the isotropy groups are all finite then their classifying spaces have trivial rational cohomology and a version of the Vietoris Mapping Theorem gives the rational equivalence asked for in Q2.  Alternatively, one could take singular simplicial sets and use a spectral sequence argument.